# Button for email template and recipient

Tags: javascript, email, custom-button, email-template

I have created a custom button(like send an email function) to define the email template and the recipient email address.
Behavior is set to execute Java, content source is OnClick Java. Code is `

> location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Order.Id}&p3_lkid={!Order.Id}&rtype=003&p3_lkid={!Order.OrderNumber}&p3_1kid={!$User.Email}&p24="xxxxx@spidernet.com&template_id=00Xw0000001U7YN');

My problem is that it defines the additional to field and not the To. See image below. Any ideas why?

[image]

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit more. For the reference of others the solution is:

1. Create a custom field button that the takes the contact's ID from the account
2. Then a lookup field on the Orders for the contacts
3. Then create a custom button as a detail page button, executing Java.

The code for the button is :

`location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Order.Id}&p3_lkid={!Order.Id}&rtype=003&p3_lkid={!Order.OrderNumber}&p3_1kid={!$User.Email}&p2_lkid={! Order.Supplier_s_ContactId__c }&template_id=00Xw0000001UHlg');`

where Supplier_s_ContactId__c is the custom field that you create on the first step. Works like a charm